# upload_max_filesize 2 sites one server

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

so, i read some questions here about this, but i think mine is special.
i have a debian server with apache2.

i would like to install two wordpress sites for two domains.
when i check the php settings in the first site and also in the other site, i see this:
[php info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hZvp.png)

but, if i check the upload_max_filesize directive, on the first site its 30M, on the other is 2M.
[upload_max_filesize 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsLF5.png)
[upload_max_filesize 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH0ly.png)

in the php.ini file this value is 50M

i would like to ask, how can i set the 2M value to upper size.

thx for help :)

Comment: 5.3? Egad man, update your server.

Comment: Hint: upload_max_filesize can be set per dir.

Comment: i would like to ask, how can i set the 2M value to upper size.

Comment: you could have Google'd this

Answer (score 0):

Use custom php.ini file for the second domain,

Follow this tutorial to make custom php.ini file.

[Custom php.ini](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-specify-a-custom-php.ini-for-a-website-apache2-with-mod_php)